# Git - Stash Full Commits

Tags: git, rebase

Is there any way to stash full commits (delta, comment, etc...)?

My use case is:

1. I have a branch A off master with 10 commits
2. I have a branch B off A with two commits
3. I make changes to A (using interactive rebasing)
4. I need to rebase B onto the new changes in A, but there is a lot of manual conflict resolution
5. I want to "stash" the top two commits in B, do a hard reset onto master, rebase onto A, and then pop my "stash"

I know I can use a temp branch and cherry-pick, but is there any way to do it in-place?

**UPDATE:**

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9
     ↑                        ↑         ↑
   master                     A         B

After making changes to A:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5A -> 6A -> 7
     ↑                          ↑     
   master                       A  

Now I'd like for B to look like

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5A -> 6A -> 7 -> 8 -> 9
     ↑                          ↑         ↑
   master                       A         B
```

Using my cherry-pick solution (is there an alternative to this that would also not have any conflicts?)

```
git checkout B
git branch tmp_B

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5A -> 6A -> 7 -> 8 -> 9
     ↑                          ↑         ↑
   master                       A         B   
                                        tmp_B

git reset master --hard

1 -> 2
     ↑
   master
     B

git rebase A

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5A -> 6A -> 7
     ↑                          ↑     
   master                       A  
                                B

git cherry-pick 8..9 // no merge conflicts
git branch -D tmp_B

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5A -> 6A -> 7 -> 8 -> 9
     ↑                          ↑         ↑
   master                       A         B
```

Comment: You lost me at step 5.  Can you show us, by way of a branch diagram, what you want to do here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure how to make a branch diagram (what's the best way to do that), but I'll update to describe the equivalent steps in terms of a cherry-pick.

Comment: Just tell us where you want those 2 commits from B to end up.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated the question.

Comment: So is your ultimate goal to update A, B, both or something else?  I think your suggested approach is probably unnecessary.

Comment: My goal is to have B stay the same, but have it rebased on A without having to manually merge the diff.

Comment: There is no way to avoid merge conflicts like this.  Just rebase B on A and deal with it.  The conflicts are caused by friction in the code and cherry picking won't get around this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've been using cherry-picking successfully until now, but it's a lot of steps. I'm updating the question again to be more clear.

Comment: I really need a diagram.  Use something like this:

Comment: **A**: `... c1 -- c2 -- c3`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the question using a diagram style that I found another question

Comment: "*I make changes to A*" when you say "changes" from your diagram it looks like you don't mean commits but an interactive rebase. Is that so?

Comment: @Schwern yes, that's what I meant :-)

Comment: @Eliezer That changes things, no pun intended. See if my updates to my answer help. And the Unicode arrows are neat, I'm gonna start using those in my Git diagrams.

Comment: @Schwern: I've tried using Unicode arrows in postings. The problem is they're not in everyone's fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there any way to stash full commits (delta, comment, etc...)?*

Not as far as I know. You'd make a temporary branch instead. The commits are already in a branch, so you effectively already have what you need.

> *I need to rebase B onto the new changes in A, but there is a lot of manual conflict resolution*

Cherry picking instead of rebasing will not help because rebasing *is* cherry picking, it's just a bunch of cherry picking in series. Because conflicts in Git are generally the result of content conflicts, not merge algorithm goofs, there's rarely a clever way around conflicts. You'll have to deal with the conflicts either way.

You could cherry pick the two commits out of B instead of rebasing, but unless something very weird is going on that will result in the same conflicts.

---

Note, that since it looks like your "changes to A" are the result of an interactive rebase, your repo looks like this:

```
                              A
                              ↓
                 5A -> 6A -> 7A
                /     
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9
     ↑                                  ↑
   master                               B
```

If you simply `git checkout B; git rebase A` then Git might get confused. It will might try to rebase commits 5 to 9 onto 7A. That will probably result in conflicts between 5 and 5A, and 6 and 6A.

Instead, you can rebase just 8 and 9 with `git rebase --onto A 7 B`. That will rebase everything between 7 and B, but not including 7. It is, effectively, cherry picking 8 and 9 onto A. Alternatively you can `git cherry-pick 8 9`, but it's better to get used to the `git rebase --onto here from to` syntax as it's more generally applicable to any branch of a branch.

Comment: I'll agree with this.  For just a few ad-hoc commits using cherry-pick would probably be my choice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think I know what's happening, see edits.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking onto but for just two commits I didn't see the point of posting.